# programicallly create radiocheck listview

Tags: android

below is my code which create listview programically how i wil change this to radiolistview in listview what wil i do to change my code to show radio list???????? i want to change my listview which i show inside alert dailog to radio check listview

```
   ublic class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnItemClickListener{

private Button btn_listviewdialog=null;

private String TitleName[]={"Sunil Gupta","Ram Chnadra"," Abhishek Tripathi","Amit  
    Verma","Sandeep Pal","Awadhesh Diwakar","Shishir Verma","Ravi Vimal","Prabhakr Singh","Manish 
      Srivastva","Jitendra Singh","Surendra Pal"};
private ArrayList<String> array_sort;

  private AlertDialog myalertDialog=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_listviewdialog=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_listviewdialog);
    btn_listviewdialog.setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {

    AlertDialog.Builder myDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    final ListView listview=new ListView(MainActivity.this);
    array_sort=new ArrayList<String> (Arrays.asList(TitleName));
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout.addView(listview);
    myDialog.setView(layout);
    CustomAlertAdapter arrayAdapter=new CustomAlertAdapter(MainActivity.this, 
              array_sort);
    listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    myDialog.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    myalertDialog=myDialog.show();

}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

        myalertDialog.dismiss();
        String strName=TitleName[position];
    //  txt_item.setText(strName);
}

     }










                 public class CustomAlertAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

Context ctx=null;
ArrayList<String> listarray=null;
private LayoutInflater mInflater=null;
public CustomAlertAdapter(Activity activty, ArrayList<String> list)
{
    this.ctx=activty;
    mInflater = activty.getLayoutInflater();
    this.listarray=list;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {

    return listarray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {       
  final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null ) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.alertlistrow, null);

        holder.titlename = (TextView)  
           convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_titllename);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String datavalue=listarray.get(position);


    if(position == getCount()-1){ 
        holder.titlename.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

    }

    holder.titlename.setText(datavalue);

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView titlename;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this???

```
  int to[] = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
  String from[] = new String[] { values };

 SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;
 simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(getSherlockActivity(), ArrList,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, from, to);
 listView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: im creating listview programiclaly what will i do any idea? help me please